# How to display a column total from an access databse in a textbox in vb?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to display the sum total of a column in a access databse for a vb program. I've written the following code, but it doesn't do anything - the textbox is still on the default value when the program runs.

```
    Dim command As OleDbCommand
    Dim data_reader As OleDbDataReader

    connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=H:\Computing\Year 13\Computing Project Course-work\Database41.accdb")

    command = New OleDbCommand("SELECT SUM(Distance) As Int32 FROM [Table3];", Conn)
    dr = command.ExecuteReader

    While dr.Read
        TextBox7.Text = dr.GetValue(4)
    End While
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one column returned from that command.
You can't use try to read a value from column at index 4, it simply doesn't exist. And you should get an exception for this attempt. If you don't see the exception only means that you have somewhere an empty try/catch block that hides your error. You should use `dr.GetValue(0)` but giving the fact that you use a scalar function in your query (SUM) then it is better to use `ExecuteScalar`

```
Using connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=H:\Computing\Year 13\Computing Project Course-work\Database41.accdb")
Using command = New OleDbCommand("SELECT SUM(Distance) As Total FROM [Table3];", Conn)
    Dim total = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar)
    TextBox7.Text = total.ToString
End Using
End Using
```

(Notice that disposable objects like the connection, commands, and Readers should be disposed when you have finished to use them. The using block ensures this)